# Share data across requests

Tags: .net, database, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core

Lets have imaginary table Foo with Id and Name. We execute 2 parallel requests to web application. Both requests process some logic, and then as part of this logic there is check on table by name (foo.name == request.name). If this entry do not exist in database create it.

How would you go about problem where 2 requests try to create same entry with same name, but only one such entry can exist? Pseudocode to illustrate problem bellow.

```
Process(Request request) 
{
    // some logic that takes around 3000ms
    
    var foo = context.Foos.SingleOrDefault(f => f.Name == request.Name)

    if (foo == null)
    {
        context = new Foo { Name = request.Name }
        context.Foos.Add(foo)
    }
    
    car.Foo = foo;
    context.Cars.Add(car);
    context.SaveChanges()
}
```